# macOS Big Sur putting external HDDs to sleep

Tags: macos, big-sur

I just got the new Mac mini M1 set up earlier this week, and for the life of me, I can't figure out why it keeps putting my external hard drives to sleep.

I have four drives, one of which is being used as the Time Machine backup. These hard drives are all in one four-bay enclosure, connected via USB 3.0. I have triple checked, multiple times that the setting under Energy Saver that says "put hard disks to sleep when possible" is ***not*** checked.

I'm running macOS Big Sur (11.0.1) and wondering if this issue is related directly to macOS? Does anyone have any suggestions, or can confirm a similar issue with macOS Big Sur?

Comment: Try **checking** the 'put hard disks to sleep" checkbox, close System Preferences, re-open Energy Saver, then **unchecking** the checkbox. On rare occasions, toggling the setting can reset what might be a munged up value in the .plist file. You might want to try executing the Terminal command `pmset -a disksleep 0` which is another way to make the change. Take a look at `man pmset` in Terminal for all the details.

Comment: This is a problem I have seen on several M1 based machines with Big Sur and external USB drives - So far I have not found an answer. "pmset -g" shows that diskskeep is set to 0(zero), but the drives still sleep within seconds of no activity.